# Cleanest way to filter an array with strings and numbers

Tags: javascript

I wonder which is the cleanest way to filter an array that have a mix of strings and numbers to give the best result based in the parameter of the function.

I have this array

```js
const vehicles = [{
  Brand: 'Peugeot',
  Type: 'Car',
  Modelo: '206',
  Puertas: 4,
  Precio: 200000
},
{
  Brand: 'Honda',
  Type: 'Motorcycle',
  Modelo: 'Titan',
  Cilindrada: '125cc',
  Precio: 60000
},{
  Brand: 'Peugeot',
  Type: 'Car',
  Modelo: '208',
  Puertas: 5,
  Precio: 250000
},{
  Brand: 'Yamaha',
  Type: 'Motorcycle',
  Modelo: 'YBR',
  Cilindrada: '160cc',
  Precio: 80500
}]
```

And I want for example when I search for 'y' the function return

```js
{
  Brand: 'Yamaha',
  Type: 'Motorcycle',
  Modelo: 'YBR',
  Cilindrada: '160cc',
  Precio: 80500
}
```

My first approach was this function

```js
function filterByValue(array, value) {
  return array.filter((data) =>  JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
```

But it's returns the whole `vehicles` array

Comment: Yeah, the reason that's returning the whole vehicles array is that it's matching the keys as well

Comment: Do you only want it to search the Brand? Because in your example a search for "y" should return the other Motorc"y"cle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for values which, when turned into strings, contain the substring being searched for:

```js
const vehicles = [{
  Brand: 'Peugeot',
  Type: 'Car',
  Modelo: '206',
  Puertas: 4,
  Precio: 200000
},
{
  Brand: 'Honda',
  Type: 'Motorcycle',
  Modelo: 'Titan',
  Cilindrada: '125cc',
  Precio: 60000
},{
  Brand: 'Peugeot',
  Type: 'Car',
  Modelo: '208',
  Puertas: 5,
  Precio: 250000
},{
  Brand: 'Yamaha',
  Type: 'Motorcycle',
  Modelo: 'YBR',
  Cilindrada: '160cc',
  Precio: 80500
}];

const input = 'y'.toLowerCase();
console.log(
  vehicles.filter(
    vehicle => Object.values(vehicle).some(
      val => String(val).toLowerCase().includes(input)
    )
  )
);
```

If you wanted to be fancier, you could sort the results by which has the most occurrences of the substring, or give extra weight to values that start with the input, or sort by the levenshtein distance from the input.

Comment: That function would never find any entries containing a capital letter as `input`.

Answer (score 1):

The following implementation uses your `JSON.stringify` logic but only applies it to the `values` in each object.

```js
const vehicles = [
  {
    Brand: "Peugeot",
    Type: "Car",
    Modelo: "206",
    Puertas: 4,
    Precio: 200000,
  },
  {
    Brand: "Honda",
    Type: "Motorcycle",
    Modelo: "Titan",
    Cilindrada: "125cc",
    Precio: 60000,
  },
  {
    Brand: "Peugeot",
    Type: "Car",
    Modelo: "208",
    Puertas: 5,
    Precio: 250000,
  },
  {
    Brand: "Yamaha",
    Type: "Motorcycle",
    Modelo: "YBR",
    Cilindrada: "160cc",
    Precio: 80500,
  },
];

function filterByValue(array, value) {
  return array.filter(
    (data) =>
      JSON.stringify(Object.values(data))
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );
}

console.log(filterByValue(vehicles, "y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would check for `value` only in the property values of the objects in your array:

```js
const vehicles = [{
    Brand: 'Peugeot',
    Type: 'Car',
    Modelo: '206',
    Puertas: 4,
    Precio: 200000
  },
  {
    Brand: 'Honda',
    Type: 'Motorcycle',
    Modelo: 'Titan',
    Cilindrada: '125cc',
    Precio: 60000
  }, {
    Brand: 'Peugeot',
    Type: 'Car',
    Modelo: '208',
    Puertas: 5,
    Precio: 250000
  }, {
    Brand: 'Yamaha',
    Type: 'Motorcycle',
    Modelo: 'YBR',
    Cilindrada: '160cc',
    Precio: 80500
  }
]


const filterByValue = (array, value) => {
  return array.filter((data) =>
    Object.values(data).some((val) =>
      val.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    )
  )
}

console.log(filterByValue(vehicles, 'y'));
```